# Best way to count cells in pd DataFrame based on value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, count

I have a pd DataFrame `mat`. From this DataFrame, I want to get the count of cells that contain a specific value (>0.5 in this case). To do so, I used:

```
mat[mat[:] > 0.5].count().sum()
```

This seems like a lot of code for a simple application. Is this the most efficient way to get the count?

Answer (score 1):

Use `sum` only with `mask` for count `True`s values:

```
(mat > 0.5).sum()
```

If need total `sum`:

```
np.sum(mat > 0.5).sum()

(mat > 0.5).sum().sum()
```

Or if convert values to 2d numpy array `np.sum` return scalar:

```
np.sum(mat.to_numpy() > 0.5)
```

Comment: This returns a list with the count per column, not the total count. 
The following does work:

`(mat > 0.5).sum().sum()`

Comment: @Emil - Understand, added to answer also with one altrnative